# Android accessibility talkback to say fragment's title

Tags: android, android-fragments, accessibility, talkback

Is there a way to get the talkback function in Android accessibility to say something after a fragment transaction? I basically want the talkback to say the name/title of the fragment after switching. These titles are set as the titles of the action bar, can they be accessed there? A user can move their finger on top of the text in the action bar to know what screen they are on, but the user won't know that unless they were familiar with the app already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can force a `WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED` event from the decor view to announce the `ActionBar` title. This will also cause `TalkBack` to clear accessibility focus, so you should only call it when the app's primary content changes.

```
getWindow().getDecorView()
        .sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED);
```

Comment: This does not seem to work, any Idea if things have changed over the period?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way since Android 9 is to set an **accessibility pane title** on the root view of your Fragment. Here's the backwards-compatible way which works on API 19+:

```kt
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityPaneTitle(view, "My fragment title")
```

If you're using AppCompat, you can also provide the title in your XML layout in a backwards-compatible way:

```
android:accessibilityPaneTitle="@string/fragment_title"
```

The title will be announced automatically when the new fragment is swapped in.

For more information read the [official Android documentation for accessibility pane titles](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles#a11y-pane-titles).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
binding.rootView.announceForAccessibility("My fragment title")
```

in onViewCreated() function of your fragment.

If you are not using viewBinding then just use the root view of the fragment's layout to call the function announceForAccessibility()