# How to avoid TalkBack from reading dismissed fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, accessibility, talkback

I'm developing a simple app that is structured in Activities and Fragments, one of the requirements its to make it accessible so I did all the content decriptions, navigaction, focus, etc.

And it works great, except with fragments, if there is an activity that loads a fragment the talkback reads its content, then the user clicks on something and a detail fragment that could be added on top of the stack.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
audios = AudiosListFragment.newInstance(params);
ft.add(R.id.audios_fragment_holder, audios);
ft.commit();
```

If the user keeps navigating talkback still remember the position of each element of the missing fragment.

Is there any way to clear the Accessibility list of events and force it to get it again? Accesibility manager does not seem to have any method for that.

```
AccessibilityManager manager = (AccessibilityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
    manager.getAccessibilityServiceList();
```

-- EDITED --
Things that I've tried and did not work out.

Sending an event from the view creation in the fragment.

```
    AccessibilityEvent event =
    AccessibilityEvent.obtain(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED);
    AccessibilityDelegate delegate = new AccessibilityDelegate();
    v.setAccessibilityDelegate(delegate);
    delegate.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(container, event);
```

Interrupting all the pending texts on the onResume of the fragment.

```
 AccessibilityManager mgr = (AccessibilityManager)
 getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
 mgr.interrupt();
```

Requesting the decorator view to register an event of window_content_change or window_state_change.

```
 getWindow().getDecorView()
    .sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED);
```

-- EDITED --
Made a DumpView Hierarchy and in there is no trace of the dismissed fragment, but talkback stills navigates it :(

Thanks, I hope someone can throw some light on this issue :)

Regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987542/android-accessibility-talkback-to-say-fragments-title

Comment: thanks, that actually clear the focus, but if the fragment is added its still posible to navigate on the underneath fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I found so the fragments below don't get read is replacing them on the fragment transaction, which is a drawback cause you loose the state of that fragment...

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
BookDetailFragment book = BookDetailFragment.newInstance(id);
ft.replace(R.id.books_fragment_holder, book);
ft.addToBackStack(BookDetailFragment.TAG);
ft.commit();
```

Im going to keep looking on how to do this correctly.

Comment: Have you found another solution for this problem?

Comment: @moxi Can you please suggest the solution you found? Replacing the fragment every time won't be a generic solution I assume

Comment: The only viable solution that I can suggest is to replace your fragments with activities. I was asking @Goofyahead if he found something.

Answer (score 2):

https://medium.com/@guygriv/accessibility-and-fragment-transactions-1aef5596f9d4

I found this, which pretty resolved the problem without the need to use replace,

This link describes on Fragment back stack change, Check this the fragment added is not the last fragment then set the Accessibility to IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS to disable hidden fragment accessibility otherwise for the fragment that is visible set Accessibility to IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25143416)

Comment: Hey, I added the Explanation, can you let me know why voted down?

Comment: I didn't downvote so I can't really speak for whoever did, but I'm guessing that it was the lack of explanation before the edit.